# multiple namespace in camel header

Tags: apache-camel

trying to call external soap service using camel cxf bean, but not sure how we can pass multiple namespace in setHeader.

setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, constant("http://test.org/Imports"))

here for one of operation, need to pass 2 namespace as
http://test.org/Imports
http://globe.org/schema

Let me know how we can add the above two namespace in camel header as operation namespace before calling cxf bean

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, AFAIK a SOAP operation of a WSDL cannot have two namespaces. The operation belongs to one namespace. Until today this was always the target namespace of the WSDL for me.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" ...
    targetNamespace="[YourOperationNamespace]">
```

I assume you have another namespace of an XML schema (embedded or external) for data types of the request or response. But this is just the definition of the payload.